# Break lines in <input> tag HTML + CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have  tag with type "text", with limit to 2,000 characters. 
I want to break lines, but " word-wrap: break-word;" not working because its not a div..

here is the css :

```
  background: #ffffff;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #CBD5DD;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 450px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 33px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  padding-left:5px;
  vertical-align:top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

any suggestions ? 
thanks

Comment: So your using an <input> element and you want it have break lines? I think <textarea> is the appropriate element for this.

Comment: Why not use a `textarea` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Cannot change line in `input[type="text"]` You have to use `Textarea` or any element with `contenteditable="true"`

**For Example**

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
  background: #ffffff;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #CBD5DD;
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-height: 70px;
  max-width: 450px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 33px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have line breaks in a `input[type="text"]` as it does not support multiple lines, use a `textarea` instead.